# How can I synchronize stickies between Macs?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, to-do, stickies

I really like the stickies that come with OS X. I know there are some more advanced "to do" lists, but I kind of like the simplicity and solid design / ux of the native ones.

[image: Picture 2.png]

How can I synchronize stickies between Macs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using Notational Velocity instead?

alternate (newer, better maintained): http://brettterpstra.com/project/nvalt/

original: http://notational.net/

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish very basic synchronization via services like Dropbox.

1. Exit Stickies.
2. To sync via Dropbox:

   ```
   ln -s ~/Library/StickiesDatabase ~/Dropbox/StickiesDatabase
   ```

   or Google Drive:

   ```
   mv ~/Library/StickiesDatabase ~/Dropbox
   ln -s ~/Google\ Drive/StickiesDatabase ~/Library/StickiesDatabase
   ```
3. Repeat steps 1 & 2 on your other Mac(s).

This method is effective, but not very robust.  Stickies saves all stickies in one file, and blindly updates it whenever you make a change. And file sync services will not merge a single file, but outright replace it (although they will try to avoid losing your data if changes are detected on both machines).

So, **this will only work properly if Stickies is closed on other machines** when creating, editing or deleting notes.

Answer (score 2):

Sticky doesn't sync natively between Macs. Notes does via iCloud and you can choose to export all stickies directly to notes.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this app:

http://itunes.apple.com/br/app/memo-sticky-notes/id454167841?mt=12

It looks just like stickies and has the functionality that you are looking for. And it's free!

Hope it helps.